# Pyspark - Transform columns with maximum values into separate 1 and 0 entries

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, etl

I have a working version for this problem in pandas, but I'm having trouble translating it to pyspark.

My **input** DataFrame looks like the following:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1],
    'cat_1': [2],
    'cat_2': [2],
    'cat_3': [1]
})
test_df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(test_df)
test_df_spark.show()

+---+-----+-----+-----+
| id|cat_1|cat_2|cat_3|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  1|    2|    2|    1| <- non-maximum
+---+-----+-----+-----+
         ^     ^
         |     |
     maximum maximum
```

I would like to:

1. Obtain columns (1 or more) with maximum value across cat_1, cat_2, cat_3. In the example, these would be cat_1 and cat_2.
2. These columns should have a 1 value. The rest of non-maximum columns will be set to 0.
3. Columns with 1 value should be divided into separate rows.

The **resulting** DataFrame should then look like this:

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+
| id|cat_1|cat_2|cat_3|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  1|    1|    0|    0|
|  1|    0|    1|    0|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

**Currently**, the most I've been able to figure out is how to set columns to 1 or 0 according to their value (whether it's the maximum or not), but I'm still missing how to generate additional entries:

```
columns = ['cat_1', 'cat_2', 'cat_3']
(
    test_df_spark
    .withColumn(
        'max_value',
        F.greatest(
            *columns
        )
    )
    .select(
        'id',
        *[F.when(F.col(c) == F.col('max_value'), F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0)).alias(c) for c in columns]
    )
    .show()
)

+---+-----+-----+-----+
| id|cat_1|cat_2|cat_3|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  1|    1|    1|    0|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your current result is `df1`:

```
columns = ['cat_1', 'cat_2', 'cat_3']
df1 = (
    test_df_spark
    .withColumn(
        'max_value',
        F.greatest(
            *columns
        )
    )
    .select(
        'id',
        *[F.when(F.col(c) == F.col('max_value'), F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0)).alias(c) for c in columns]
    )
)
```

You can manipulate `df1` to get your desired results by creating an array of structs and `inline` it:

```
df2 = df1.select(
    'id', 
    F.array(*[
        F.when(
            F.col(c1) == 1, 
            F.struct(*[
                F.lit(1).alias(c2) if i1 == i2 else F.lit(0).alias(c2) 
                for i2, c2 in enumerate(columns)
            ])
        ) 
        for i1, c1 in enumerate(columns)
    ]).alias('cat')
).selectExpr(
    'id', 
    'inline(filter(cat, x -> x is not null))'
)

df2.show()
+---+-----+-----+-----+
| id|cat_1|cat_2|cat_3|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  1|    1|    0|    0|
|  1|    0|    1|    0|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
```